# Python Paramiko, reading line(s) from file

Tags: python, paramiko

First of all, I'm a noob with Python so this is gonna seem like a really easy question probably.

I'm trying to figure out how to use Python Paramiko, and have succeeded in connecting to my remote server, so I've succeeded in the first respect. What I would like to do now is to read a particular line from a file.

I've looked through Paramiko and it looks like the BufferedFile class might be able to read lines from the file. However I can't figure out how I need to load the file within the class. There is no 'open file' method, with the other methods just stating that they do things to 'the file'. The constructer doesn't take a file, so how do I load a file which I use the methods on? Probably a big thing I've missed, but I'm learning, so please excuse me.

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of an abstract class, not supposed to be directly instantiated. The constructor of its subclass, [`SFTPFile`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPFile-class.html), is more meaningful, although not exactly well-documented. You may also want to look at [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org). It's a layer on top of `paramiko` that I find more nice to use.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the SFTP subsystem.

Once you have a `Transport` instance and you have successfully authenticated, get an `SFTP` client:

```
sftp_client = my_transport.open_sftp_client()
```

Once you have that, you can open a remote file using the `open()` method:

```
my_file = sftp_client.open('remote_file.txt', 'r')

# use my_file, it is a file-like object, for example:
print my_file.read(100)

my_file.close()
```